# Using Callback Rails with parameter - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

EDITED:

I trying to refactore this:

```
self.before_create do |obj|
  obj.position = self.class.count
end
```

to this:

```
self.before_create :set_position

private

def set_position
  obj.position = self.class.count
end
```

But, Its displaying Error:

```
 undefined local variable or method `obj'
```

How fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class YourClass < AR

  before_create :set_position

  private

  def set_position
    self.position = @@count
  end
end
```

The `set_position` method is instance method, so `self` is assigned to the instance. The `count` I believe should be a class variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Something < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_position

  protected
  def set_position
    self.position = self.class.count
  end
end
```

Be aware that if you use class variables you might run into trouble if your server uses multiple processes (`@@count` getting out of sync between them). A functional style queries `count` from the db.

**Note:** A lot of this behavior (including properly implemented atomic changes to lists) can be found in the [acts_as_list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) gem, that used to be part of Rails a while back. I suggest using that.

Comment: I do not understand, I've changed but the error persists... se my question please

Comment: I've updated the answer, hopefully it makes more sense. Did you go with acts_as_list or a custom fix in the end?